# ssas tabular model use roles so customer can only see suppliers used

Tags: ssas-tabular

I have a ssas tabular model that has dimCustomrer, dimSupplier and a fact table.

I created a role for customers so they can only see themselves and this works perfectly fine.

Is it possible for the role to filter the Dimsupplier table so they can only see the suppliers they have used?
Searching google I can't find anything that seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to filter dimSupplier based on the fact table? Yes, that is possible by enabling bi-directional filtering on the relationship between dimSupplier and the fact table, and also setting the security filtering behaviour to "both directions":

[image]

However, bi-directional filtering can have some performance impact if your model contains large amounts of data.

Alternatively, you could import an aggregated version of the fact table, that only contains all the distinct combinations of customers and suppliers (2 columns). Call this table **BridgeCustomerSupplier**, or something like that. Then, you add a row-level filter to your role on the dimSupplier table, and use `LOOKUPVALUE`, to see if there's a matching record in BridgeCustomerSupplier, for the current supplier (in dimSupplier - the row context), and the current customer.